# How to sort articles by filename in pelican?

Tags: python, pelican

In Pelican 3.5 I know I can sort articles by attributes, like

```
ARTICLE_ORDER_BY = 'title'
```

but I would like to order by the filename. It is much easier to change the filenames than to open each file and edit the attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ARTICLE_ORDER_BY = 'filename'
```

or

```
ARTICLE_ORDER_BY = lambda x:os.path.basename(x.source_path or '')
```

Comment: thanks. the second one works. I don't know why the first one doesn't, and it doesn't with 'basename' either.